# Replace a range of numbers in a list with the sum of numbers in that range (Python)

Tags: python, list

I am trying to replace a range of numbers in a list with the sum of numbers in that range.  Note, I do not want to replace the entire list, only a specific range within that list.

Here is my code:

```
nodes_list = [[1], [2], [3]]
new_dict = {1: [1], 2: [1, 2], 3: [1, 3]}
O_D_list = [[1, 1, 0], [1, 2, 100], [1, 3, 150]]

b = max(new_dict)

for key in new_dict:

    for i in nodes_list:
        if i[0] in new_dict[key]:
            i.append(sum(O_D_list[b-1][2]))
             #this is where I am stuck.  I would like to get the SUM of the numbers in range O_D_list[b-1][2] and then append only that sum to nodes_list.

    b -= 1

print ('nodes list', nodes_list)
print ('O_D_list', O_D_list)
print ('b', b)
```

Here is my output:

```
File "location", line 13, in <module>    
i.append(sum(O_D_list[b-1][2]))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

The output that I would like is:

```
nodes_list = [[1, 250], [2, 100], [3, 0]]
```

If you remove the "sum()" from line 13 you get the following output:

```
nodes list [[1, 150, 100, 0], [2, 100], [3, 0]]
O_D_list [[1, 1, 0], [1, 2, 100], [1, 3, 150]]
b 0
```

Thus I know that I want `nodes_list[0][1]` to be equal to 250: (150 + 100).  But I only want to display that sum.

Thanks!

Comment: To explain the output you get: `sum(O_D_list[b-1][2])` is computing eg. `sum(150)` as `b=3` in the first iteration. summing over a single value does not make much sense. Is what you want `O_D_list[0][2]+O_D_list[1][2]+O_D_list[2][2]`?

Comment: Hi! I ran `sum(O_D_list[ : ][2]` and I get an output of: `nodes list [[1, 154, 154, 154], [2, 154], [3, 154]]`  so that means that it's giving me 150 + 3 + 1.  But I thanks for letting me know what's happening for `sum(O_D_list[b-1][2])`, that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Can you better explain what your ranges are meant to do in particular `[1]`? I don't understand why that value picks the last element of each sublist.

Comment: I'll write up a possible answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
nodes_list = [[1], [2], [3]]
new_dict = {1: [1], 2: [1, 2], 3: [1, 3]}
O_D_list = [[1, 1, 0], [1, 2, 100], [1, 3, 150]]

b = max(new_dict)
for key,value in new_dict.items():
    for i in nodes_list:
        if i[0] in value and len(i)==1:
            i.append(sum((x[2] for x in O_D_list[:b])))
    b -= 1
```

To explain the code:

- In the second to last line it loops over a specific index in a nested loop we use a generator expression which generates a pseudolist of all values with index 2 in a sublist, using only the first `b` sublists. This is then summed and added to the list `i`.
- In your code you continue adding values to nodeslist[0] because you loop over `nodes_list` every time you access a new key-value pair from `new_dict`. A (poor) quickfix to handle this in the above code was to only append if `i` only contains one value. I do not know what you intend to do with this code, but I would guess a reasonable improvement would be to adjust the structure of `nodes_list`,`new_dict` and/or `O_D_list`.

Output:

```
[[1, 250], [2, 100], [3, 0]]
```

Comment: In a lecture, this looks good though. Will get back to you in 45mins. Thank you!

Comment: Ok, so after testing out your code on a larger example I've realised that I didn't fully define the problem.  What I've realized I need to do is:  Step 1: check if `b` is in the `new_dict` values and also check if `b` can be found in any of the lists within `O_D_list`.   If `b` can be found within `new_dict` and `O_D_list` we then append the third item of the list in `O_D_list` that `b` was found in to all of the values in `nodes_list`.  @M. T I'll make a new question for this. Thanks again for your help though.